# Why does du -b show a different result than stat?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, du

I've recently ran into this problem:

```
find /tmp/tmp33hn25wv -type f -exec stat --format='%s' {} + | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
10420224

du -bs /tmp/tmp33hn25wv
12198004    /tmp/tmp33hn25wv
```

Results are consistently different.  All files are written in multiples of block-size bytes.

Where does [du](https://ss64.com/bash/du.html) find these extra bytes?  I understand that file-system may need more or less space to store the contents of the files, but I hoped that `-b` option to `du` means that it has to count the "apparent" size, not the size used by file system...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`du` includes the size of directories. If you add `-type d` to the `find` criteria you may get the result you want (I do on a directory tree containing only standard files):

```
find /tmp/tmp33hn25wv \( -type f -o -type d \) -exec stat --format='%s' {} + |\
    awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

However, there may be other file types that take up space, so try omitting the type check altogether:

```
find /tmp/tmp33hn25wv -exec stat --format='%s' {} + | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Comment: This is interesting. I'll have to check it when I'm back at work. However, what's "apparent" size of a directory? I understand that, in terms of file-system, directories do take space, but what counts towards that space, when `du` counts it? Is it the inode structure? Is it the entire entries list?

Comment: Directories seem to be allocated in multiples of 4096 bytes (at least on my disc with 4KiB block size). Without checking, I assume that directories are padded with empty entries to fill the allocated blocks.

Comment: What happens with my alternative `find` commands?

Comment: OK, it does seem to be coming from directories. When I run the same command, but for directories rather than files, I do get the same figure `du` would produce. So, now the question boils down to what does `du` measure when it measures a directory.

Comment: Whenever `ls -l` lists a directory, it shows a multiple of the block size: as I said before, I assume the allocated size is filled with blank entries, so that the allocated and apparent sizes are always the same. Note that other file types, such as FIFOs and symbolic links, may occupy disc space, which would mean that the difference need not be a multiple of the directory count.

Comment: My tests have been done on `ext4`, and full details are [here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout). Other file systems will have different directory formats.

Comment: I'm quite sure there aren't any other file types in that directory. What bothers me is that how much space to allocate to a file or a directory is an entirely file-system specific thing, so, the real allocated space is not something I'd expect `du` to have any knowledge of. Think of situations like systems which do snapshots: should they count the data + metadata in snapshots towards that number for example? What if they deduplicated, truncated, or fragmented data in other ways etc? Obviously `du` wouldn't know that.

Comment: "Apparent" size on the other hand, is something that filesystem guarantees to show to the user.  Say, you are using ZFS, and you've written a file of 100GB of zeros. The filesystem will only use couple of blocks to store that file, i.e. depending on your block device, something between 20 and 4000 bytes.  While `du` would report having `100GB` of data there, if asked for apparent size.  What apparent size directories have--beats me. I'd think they have none, because there's no way you can `open()` them, but apparently, they do...

Comment: From what I can see from the ext4 structure link, the apparent size seems to be the size stored in the inode entry, but I don't know of an easy way to read the raw inode entries to confirm this.